# Subseting a list in R based on another list

Tags: r

I would like to subset the elements of list1 based on the ones in list 2. I tried using a `for loop` but it appears not work. Is there any way to work around it?

```
list1 <- list("a" = "Variable label a",
              "b" = "Variable label b",
              "c" = "Variable label c",
              "d" = "Variable label d",
              "e" = "Variable label e"
              )

list2 <- list(
  "Variable label a" = "Variable label a",
  "Variable label c" = "Variable label c",
  "Variable label e" = "Variable label e"
  
)


subset <- vector("list")

for (nm in list1){
  if (nm %in% list2){
    subset <- list1
  }
}
```

Comment: What should the final output look like?

Comment: You could try to use `purrr::keep`: `list1 |> purrr::keep( names(list1) %in% (names(list2) |> stringr::str_sub(-1,-1)))`

Comment: @Julian I got an error while replicating it.Error: unexpected '>' in "purrr::keep: list1 |>"

Comment: @sindri_baldur the output should look like list1 but now with only the elements in list 2

Comment: @chrisjude it is the native pipe which has been available since R version 4.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
list1 |> purrr::keep(names(list1) %in% (names(list2) |> stringr::str_sub(-1,-1)))
```

**Output**:

```
$a
[1] "Variable label a"

$c
[1] "Variable label c"

$e
[1] "Variable label e"
```

Comment: Perfect! This is what I wanted!